# Why does printing text containing a line break with ajax result in error?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm using jQuery/ajax to print text after a click. But when the text contains a line break, this action results in an error.

```
@model.text = "line
               another line"


<!-- ERB -->

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#click-to-show%>").click(function() {
    $("#text-wrapper").html("<%= @model.text %>");
  });
</script>
```

How can I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript does not allow literal line breaks in it's strings.
Change your code to `@model.text = "line\\nanother line"`

BTW, this is not proper AJAX. You're not doing asynchronous requests.

With proper AJAX, you have a separate page just to print out the data, something like:

```
@model.text = "line
               another line"
<!-- ERB -->
<%= @model.text %>
```

And within your original file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#click-to-show%>").click(function() {
    $.get('URL-TO-THAT-SEPEARTE-PAGE', function(result) {
        $("#text-wrapper").html(result);
    })
  });
</script>
```

Comment: If it's in a comment section, how can I deal with users who type in literal line breaks?

Comment: @JeffCaros You should preprocess the user submitted text either before writing to database or before presentation.

Comment: Like use a regex to replace line breaks with "//n"?

Comment: @JeffCaros Or doing proper ajax will also be a solution

Comment: @JeffCaros I've edited my answer adding some hint on how ajax should be. But if you're producing something serious, preprocessing user input is still essential to avoid attacks.

Comment: Thanks for your excellent answer. Is there some sort of default guide to preprocessing user input?

Comment: @JeffCaros Using an ORM library instead of creating SQL yourself usually helps you to avoid injection attacks effectively. And for other validations you may refer to [this link](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Data_Validation)